# confusing file caching scenario

Tags: php, caching

I have a caching scenario which I'm not sure how to solve. I am able to cache static pages without a problem but am having a little trouble with dynamic pages.

In the dynamic page the logic goes something like this:

//part1
-some processing for the beg of the page (needed for part 3)
-echo some info

//part2
echo user specific menu + some user specific info

//part3
echo rest of the page

The problem is that if I cache the whole page, and then the cache is read, it is no good (
part2 will be incorrect since it depends on the user).

to cache a page, I just use 
"ob_start();" at the beginning of the file, then save ob_get_contents() to a file and then "ob_end_flush();" at the end.
If the file already exists in cache and its not expired, i do: "include(file);" and "exit;"

I tried splitting the caching into two files but parts 2 and 3 depend on some php processing of part1 I'm having a hard time...

Does anybody have any ideas on how to solve this? Please let me know if I'm not being very clear and I will reformulate the question. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain why you are caching this? Is it to prevent querying a database?

Comment: yes it is to prevent querying the db. I am caching the queries but also want to cache the html to prevent all the cache hits on each query (there are lots of counters being queried). Unfortunately I cannot use memcached at the moment. I don't want to cache part2 at all, I don't mind generating it every time but I'm not able to achieve caching for parts 1 and 3 and making this all work together.

Comment: In any case, I'd suggest you write a function that generates each part and have that function handle the caching for that part. Also keep in mind you can't run consecutive `ob_start` if you haven't ended them.

Comment: the code is a bit trickier, I am aware that you cannot run ob_start consecutively, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### APC/Redis/Memcached

If you could you should use [APC](http://scriptperfect.com/2009/09/php-and-apc-tutorial/)(and/or [Redis](http://antirez.com/post/redis-as-LRU-cache.html)/[Memcached](http://memcached.org/)) to cache your data because it is going to be **WAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAY** faster(everything stays in **MEMORY**). If you want your website to perform good you should have APC(precompiled byte-code in MEMORY) installed anyway.

### Cache_Lite

Else you should use the excellent [Cache_Lite](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.caching.cache-lite.php) library to cache your data to a file. [The introduction](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.caching.cache-lite.intro.php) explains perfectly how to use it. If it all possible you should write to  `/dev/shm/` because this maps to **MEMORY** which is going to be way faster then Disc IO.

### Splitting Cache

> I tried splitting the caching into two
>   files but parts 2 and 3 depend on some
>   php processing of part1 I'm having a
>   hard time...

You should have unique pieces(exclusively as large as possible would be best, but sometimes hard to keep track off) and then combine these pieces you need on that page. Each piece should have an unique ID off-course(for retrieval).

```
<?php
require_once('Cache/Lite.php');

$options = array(
    'cacheDir' => '/tmp/',
    'lifeTime' => 3600
);

// Create a Cache_Lite object
$Cache_Lite = new Cache_Lite($options);

if ($data = $Cache_Lite->get('#{ID for user specific menu}')) {
    echo($data);
} else {
    $data = 'Data of the block 1-1';
    $Cache_Lite->save($data);
}

echo('<br><br>Non cached line !<br><br>');

if ($data = $Cache_Lite->get('#{user specific info}')) {
    echo($data);
} else {
    $data = 'Data of the block 2';
    $Cache_Lite->save($data);
}

?>
```

Comment: I think the cache_lite solution (to split in two parts) suits my needs best. My only concern is that if I do that now, will I be able to easily switch to memcached in the future? Is there a sort of trigger in the cache_lite package where I could say "$memory = true" which would ignore the "cacheDir" and switch saving/loading everything to/from memory? Or would I need to make some code changes again and store the two different blocks of data using the memcached functions? Thanks so much.

Comment: You should write an wrapper for that. http://www.scribd.com/doc/4069180/Caching-Performance-Lessons-from-Facebook => Look at the cache_get function() allthough you should make it work for APC, memcached and Cache_lite

Comment: wow, that is a whole other level of caching.. apc/memcached/cache_lite are all for different purposes? If I understand correctly, cache_lite is to cache page content (html), memcached is for db query, APC is to cache PHP code? To maximize performance, all 3+ should be used as much as possible? First we try to get the cache from global vars, then we could try the saved html, if the file cache is expired then APC would kick in along with memcached and then create a new html file with Cache_Lite right?Am I missing something? it's a bit confusing. Looks like FB does not use hd (cache_lite).thanks!

Comment: @Kentor Ofcourse FB does not use cache_lite. The disc is freakin SLOW compared to MEMORY(MEM +- 80ns vs DISC +-5ms). You should not use cache_lite if you could use memory, but you can't? For now you just would have to write a wrapper function cache_get which uses first tries GLOBAL then cache_lite under the bottom. P.S: Later if I have some time I will probably update my answer a little bit.

Comment: Yes you're right I can't at the moment but hopefully will be able to should the project grow. Ok if you could provide a little more information/example (if you have time) that would be great!! thanks so much. I will try the cache_lite approach for now and let you know if it works out. thanks again!

Comment: I added a snippet to github(https://gist.github.com/785239) which you could use. It is not completely finished yet I guess, but I hope you get what I was going for. You should this cache class in your code and modify it to use memcached or apc when you upgrade instead of directly calling $Cache_Lite.

Comment: P.S: you should use https://gist.github.com/raw/785239/7ed421d52d6c04207f340473bfaf0baf456c0bce/Cache.php which has my cache library appended to the Cache_lite library. The trick to making your site faster is using as little require statements as possible because they slow you down(DISC IO is a performance killer). You should read the "IMPORTANT NOTE" part from this link http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.caching.cache-lite.intro.php (search for it). If entry is not in cache then you should require the files you need to do your computations/work etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the reason behind caching the "user specific menu" and the "user specific info" is to prevent querying a database, you could very well cache the resulting query instead of the resulting HTML.

You also mentioned that you are caching into a file. You might want to look into a cache server such as [memcached](http://memcached.org). This will reduce the load on the filesystem.

Unless you are doing intense processing in the PHP code or if you are performing a query that is taking time, I don't see the need to cache the HTML outputted by your PHP script.

Comment: I've added more info in the question comments